# Ratchet checkbox list

Tags: html, css, ratchet-bootstrap, ratchet-2

Anybody knows if is Ratchet http://goratchet.com/ has possibility to create a list of checkbox to select item?
Documentation shows only technique to make a simple list as this:

```
<ul class="table-view">
<li class="table-view-cell">Item 1 <span class="badge">4</span></li>
<li class="table-view-cell">Item 2 <span class="badge">1</span></li>
<li class="table-view-cell">Item 3 <span class="badge">5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply include your checkboxes in the list?

Comment: Is possbile modify it? Or it can generate problem?

Comment: Of course. It's plain HTML and CSS, you can do whatever you want. Maybe you need to alter the CSS a bit to get your desired results..

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty straight forward...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/xNKyL/)

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="table-view">
      <li class="table-view-cell">
          <input type="checkbox" /> Check Box
      </li>
      <li class="table-view-cell">
          <input type="checkbox" /> Check Box
      </li>
      <li class="table-view-cell">
          <input type="checkbox" /> Check Box
      </li>
      <li class="table-view-cell">
          <input type="checkbox" /> Check Box
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```